# How can I create cross-references to 'lstlsting' environments?

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

I'd like to know if it is possible to use the command `\ref` (that I use for images and equations) or a similar one to create cross-references to `lstlisting?  environments.

Doing so, I want to visualize the listing by simply clicking on the reference in the text.

I use the following command to recall the matlab file:
\lstinputlisting[caption= namecaption]{matlabcode.m}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lstlisting` environment requires users to place both `caption` and `label` information in the optional argument of the environment. E.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Hello World},label=lst:hello]
\end{lstlisting}
A cross-reference to Listing \ref{lst:hello}.
\end{document}
```

To make the cross-reference into a hyperlink, be sure to load the `hyperref` package as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Does this procedure work also if I use the command \lstinputlisting[caption= namecaption]{matlabcode.m}?

Comment: @Giuseppe, Absolutely. To verify, give `\lstinputlisting[caption=namecaption,label=lst:file]{matlabcode.m} ... A cross-reference to Listing \ref{lst:file}.` a try.